# create method in GUI Builder

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

this my GUI I designed by **Netbean Builder**
[description http://up07.s-oman.net/1hGDmMy.png](http://up07.s-oman.net/1hGDmMy.png)

 I want when the user click calculate button it will add **Rate Of Interest** with **Laon Amount** and display total in **total TextFeild**.

this my calculate method

```
public void calculate(int b){

     int num1 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()));
      int num2 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()));
    b=num1+num2;

}
```

this code in button calculate

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
calculate(b);
}
```

and this code in total TextField

```
private void jTextField6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(b));

}
```

I got nothing When I tried So what the wrong??

Comment: What exactly is `b` that you're passing to the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point of a the textfield that displays the result, needing an `ActionListener`. Try something like this, setting the text in the `calculate` method

```
public voi calculate(){
    int result;
    int num1 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()));
    int num2 = (Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()));

    jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(num1 + num2));
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   calculate();
}
```

I have idea what `b` does, but I'm assuming you're trying to pass it by reference which won't work, so I took it out.